# Setting thresholds values - Java - Static Code analysis - SonarQube Sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, checkstyle, findbugs

So we have Checkstyle, PMD, Findbugs as tools which performs static code analysis or work on bytecode to find various issues in code and using them in Jenkins/Hudson (under Post build actions), can turn a build to a unstable, failed, successful build depending upon what threshold values we set there.

As SonarQube is the upcoming/future single dash for showing all such analysis in one page for a project/module, I was wondering where in SonarQube settings (I can set such threasholds) to make a build as a failed, unstable, successful i.e. Jenkins will launch the build (ANT/Maven/Gradle etc), calls, sonarRunner (task in Gradle) / sonar-runner (executable in Linux/Unix), then if threasholds are not good, then Jenkins will mark the build as unstable/failed/successful depending upon the set threashold values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See alerts / Quality Gates section in SonarQube.(http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles#QualityProfiles-alertsEditingAlerts) and Build Breaker plugin (http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Breaker+Plugin).